# turtlebot autonomous navigation with multiple goals

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have got the turtlebot to navigate autonomously using the turtlebot tutorials. I was wondering if there is any package/tutorial out there to make the turtlebot handle multiple goals. For example, first go to goal #1, then goal#2 and so on. I assume this would not be possible using rviz and that I would have to write my own trajectory planner etc., For this, I was hoping to get hold of the source code that rviz uses and then modify it to suit my needs. Is there a way I can get the code (for sending a navigation goal and autonomously navigating there) used in rviz? Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66867/turtlebot-autonomous-navigation-with-multiple-goals/) by [turtlebotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4957/turtlebotnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-03-10**:
I'm working on a similar project. Did you ever get this going? If you did, would you share your solution?

**Comment by [guigui](https://answers.ros.org/users/16871/guigui/) on 2014-06-25**:
Hi,
I want to know if you had make this (turtlebot autonomous navigation with multiple goals), and how did you process?
thanks a lot

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-01-19**:
Did you get the code you were looking for??

**Comment by [rahul.pillai93](https://answers.ros.org/users/29614/rahul.pillai93/) on 2017-03-11**:
Hey. Can anyone provide a solution for this yet? I am trying navigation with multiple goals.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write your own node to program it. You might find move_base package documentation useful to achieve that : http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-09**:
@Lucile's answer is what I would recomend but to directly answer your question.  rviz's source can be found at: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to check out. https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_ocs/tree/hydro/yocs_waypoints_navi
This helps to navigate around multiple poses.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-06-25**:
With this package you can both click on RViz for intermediate goals or pass them in a YAML file. Also you can make both a sequence of goals or an infinitely repeated loop.